# Time cell failed on .xlsx output

Tags: phpexcel

I have the part of code that generate duration of a task to format h:mm (5:00) for my report.

```
$duration=explode(':',task_duration($item_task->duration_plan));
$time_str='=TIME('.$duration[0].';'.$duration[1].';0)';
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D' . $row, $time_str);
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D' . $row)-`enter code here`>getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);
```

So I get something like `=TIME(5:0:0)` and it should be displayed in the file like 5:00.

Everything works with .xls, but when I tried to create file in .xlsx, there is nothing in the time cell but `0`.

Then I tried to work around with this:

```
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder( new PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder() );
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D' . $row , task_duration($item_task->duration_plan) . ':00');
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D' . $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);
```

It works fine with both .xls and .xlxs, but when amount of hours is bigger than 24, the time cell is displayed not as time (25:00:00), but as string ('25:00:00) and I can't get total time for all tasks.

All my other non time-formatted cells looks fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found the way to work around it. When number is bigger than 24, i divide it to several TIME() function, then get the total of all.
For example, 30 hours would be devided to =TIME(23,0,0) + TIME(7,0,0).
In the end i get 30:00, value that i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the PHPExcel developer documentation, section 4.6.4 (`Write a formula into a cell`):

> Inside the Excel file, formulas are always stored as they would appear in an English version of Microsoft Office Excel, and PHPExcel handles all formulae internally in this format. This means that the following rules hold:
>
> - Decimal separator is '.' (period)
> - Function argument separator is ',' (comma)
> - Matrix row separator is ';' (semicolon)
> - English function names must be used

You're using a semi-colon (`;`) as an argument separator for the `TIME()` function

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it works. But there is still a problem. For TIME() when the value is bigger than 24, for example 25 , i will get in output value 01:00 , eventhought i've change the mask to [hh]:mm
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D' . $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("[hh]:mm);

Comment: Which Writer are you using?

Comment: You mean this ? 
$excelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');

Comment: Yes, I'm having difficulty understanding what the problem actually is; so if I'm going to have to set up a test to work out why this format mask isn't being handled correctly, then I prefer to do as much as I can to replicate your exact code, and how you're seeing this as a string.... so I'll create a spreadsheet and populate it with data as shown in your code, and write it as Excel2007 and check it out in MS Excel

Comment: Should i post output files somewhere, so that you could see what the result of my code ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3nj27e6yKi5MExMSmh4SEFIdEk/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3nj27e6yKi5OV93U1QtanFVenM/edit?usp=sharing

Here are 2 files for 2 part of code, report.xls is for the first, report(1).xls - second. You should better download it because google display report.xls not properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.
I got the seconds divided by 86400 and it works.

```php
$activeSheetObj->setCellValueExplicit(
    PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex).$line,
    $seconds/86400, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_NUMERIC);

$activeSheetObj->getStyle(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex++).$line)
  ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[HH]:MM:SS');
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question about displaying time values > 24:00

`FORMAT_DATE_TIME3` is a time format code `h:mm` that displays time based on a 24-hour clock, values over 24 hours will roll over to the following day, so 16:00 + 16:00 will give 1 day and `08:00` rather than `32:00` as the time; but `h:mm` suppresses days, and you won't see an hours value greater than 24 hours

If you want the hours value to exceed 24 (for example if you are adding several times together to work out a total duration) you will need to use an appropriate number format mask like `[hh]:mm`. This format **will** show `32:00` as the value for 16:00 + 16:00.

Comment: The problem is when the value is bigger than 24:00 , for example 25:00 , in my time cell it would be displayed not as a time value , 25:00 but like a string value ('25:00:00). So i cant get total string.

Do you know any other way to display time in PHPExcel properly so i could get total ?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to store a duration of hours into the cell in the format you were hoping to accomplish. I learned that you need to store the time in a decimal amount of days[1], and then apply a custom format. Much like:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D' . $row, $days + ($hours / 24) + ($minutes / (24 * 60)));
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D' . $row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('[hh]:mm:ss');`
```

This appears to open properly in both OpenOffice and Apple's Numbers. Using capital letters in the format code does not open properly in Numbers.

[1] [dd/mm/yyyy format in PHPExcel adding single quote(') in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964547/dd-mm-yyyy-format-in-phpexcel-adding-single-quote-in-cell)